# How to pass string as a body in api post method using retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit2

I am developing an android application which sends the user entered data (Through edit textboxes) and it calls a POST API Method to send this data in the body of that API

Consider API URL is "htpps://xxxxx.com/forms/xxxxxx/reponse"

content-type "Json(Application/json)"

content looks like:

```
{"answers":
"[{\"questionId\":\"r8554145065f6486d8a362bec92030a06\",\"answer1\":\"xxxxx\"},
  {\"questionId\":\"rf516c5bf916e4d6d960a1f8abc82f33b\",\"answer1\":\"xxxx\"}]"}
```

My problem is here how can I pass this type of body to retrofit and instead of "XXXXX" in content there will be a string which takes input from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably already are using a interface to make the api calls and thats where you add the String body to the request.

```
public interface YourService{
  @POST("forms/xxxxxx/reponse")
  Call<Object> makeCall(@Body String body);
}
```

If you haven't been using an interface with retrofit than you can create an instance of the above interface by using your existing RetrofitClient:

```
YourService service = retrofitClient.create(YourService.class);
```

And now you can access the api by calling makeCall on the instance of the service:

```
service.makeCall(yourCustomString).enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<MovieResponse> response) {...}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {...}
});
```

You can build "yourCustomString" with String builder or so, even though I wouldnt recommend that, instead I would use an ConverterFactory and map your JSON-Data to Java POJOs. For example Moshi (com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi).
If you do that you can use a Java POJO as the @Body annotated attribute and you simply ony set the two attributes "questionId" and "answer1" on the POJO instead of building a String.

If you would do that, you would end up with two classes:

```
public class Answer {
    @Json(name = "questionId")
    public String questionId;

    @Json(name = "answer1")
    public String answer1;
}
```

and

```
public class Body {
    @Json(name = "answers")
    private List<Answer> answers = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

Now with that you would just create an Body object and then add as many answers as you want to the answers attribute and then use the Body object as the parameter on the retrofit interface.

Note: If you do that, you have to add the MoshiConverterFactory to the RetrofitClient while building it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are already familiar with how to implement Repositories and Interfaces for making API calls.

For the case you first need a DTO for answer.

```
public class AnswerDTO
{
    private String questionId;
    private String answer1;

    public AnswerDTO(String questionId, String answer1)
    {
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.answer1 = answer1;
    }
}
```

Now you can create an Interface for API call.

```
public interface QuestionsService
{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("requestUrlHere")
    Call<Response> yourApiCall(@Field("answers[]") List<AnswerDTO> answers);
}
```

Hope this helps !.